# Ising configuration after rotation in one sub-lattice

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, spin-models

I do not understand Eq. (5.9) in Auerbach's book *Interacting electrons an quantum magnetism*. Consider the general spin-$S$ Heisenberg model on a bipartite lattice with $N$ sites:

$$
H = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i,j} J_{ij} \mathbf{S}_i \cdot \mathbf{S}_j
$$

The Hilbert space is spanned by the following basis vectors, called *Ising configurations* in the book:

$$
|\Phi_\alpha\rangle
= |S,m^\alpha_1\rangle_1 \otimes \cdots 
\otimes |S,m^\alpha_N\rangle_N
\tag{5.6}
$$

Here $|S, m_i\rangle_i$ denotes a simultaneous eigenstate of $\mathbf{S}^2_i$, $S^z_i$ with eigenvalues $S(S+1)$, $m_i$, respectively: omitting the site label, this means

$$
\mathbf{S}^2 |S,m\rangle = S(S+1) |S,m\rangle, \quad
S_z |S,m\rangle = m |S,m\rangle
$$

Then Auerbach rotates the spin operator on sub-lattice $B$ about the $z$-axis by angle $\pi$. Below we focus on a specific site in sub-lattice $B$; the site label is omitted from now on. The rotation by angle $\theta$ about $z$-axis is implemented by the operator

$$
R = \exp(i\theta S_z)
$$

Using $[S_a, S_b] = i \epsilon_{abc} S_c$, I can show that the transformed spin operators are

$$
\begin{align*}
    \tilde{S}_x &= R S_x R^{-1}
    = e^{i\theta S_z} S_x e^{-i\theta S_z}
    = S_x \cos \theta - S_y \sin \theta
    \\
    \tilde{S}_y &= R S_y R^{-1} 
    = S_x \sin \theta + S_y \cos \theta
    \\
    \tilde{S}_z &= R S_z R^{-1} = S_z
\end{align*}
$$

When $\theta = \pi$, we obtain

$$
\tilde{S}_x = -S_x, \quad 
\tilde{S}_y = -S_y, \quad 
\tilde{S}_z = S_z
\tag{5.8}
$$

After the rotation on sub-lattice $B$, the Ising configurations are transformed, too. Let $|S,\tilde{m}\rangle$ be the transformed state, such that:

$$
\tilde{S}_z |S,\tilde{m}\rangle = \tilde{m} |S,\tilde{m}\rangle
$$

I think that the transformed $|S,\tilde{m}\rangle$ should be

$$
\begin{align*}
    |S,\tilde{m}\rangle &\equiv R |S,m\rangle
    = e^{i\pi S_z} |S,m\rangle
    \\
    &= e^{i\pi m} |S,m\rangle
    = (-1)^m |S,m\rangle
\end{align*}
$$

However, Auerbach says that

$$
|S,\tilde{m}\rangle = (-1)^{S+m} |S,m\rangle
\tag{5.9}
$$

**Question:** where does this $(-1)^S$ come from?

Comment: Have you practiced with N=2, and N=3,  for *S* =1/2, $m_i=1/2$  on (5.6)?

Comment: @CosmasZachos Could you please explain why the lattice size $N$ is relevant? I think what may go wrong is $|S,\tilde{m}\rangle = R|S,m\rangle$, but this has nothing to do with $N$.

Comment: Your setup and the conceit that you only have one site is flawed. You are adding *N* spin *S* s in (5.6). They add, they are not xerox copies of each other. Taking two sites might illuminate the point.